# OpenTelemetry manual instrumentation NoClassDefFoundError - Java

Tags: java, instrumentation, open-telemetry, telemetry, otlp-grpc

I've been trying to create a SdkTracerProvider as described in the formal guide of OpenTelemetry (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/)
but keep getting a "**NoClassDefFoundError**" for **Marshaler.java** which is in opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common jar.

```
Resource resource = Resource.getDefault()
            .merge(Resource.create(Attributes.of(ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME, "logical-service-name")));

SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder()
            .addSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor.builder(OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder().build()).build())
            .setResource(resource)
            .build();
```

The exception is thrown at -

```
OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder()
```

I have defined a new library in the project structure with source and class, and created the dependency needed for the module I use. I see the class itself appears in the external libraries consumed by the project.
Also, I was able to consume other jars in the library without errors -

```
io.opentelemetry.sdk.resources.Resource
```

for example.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/exporter/internal/marshal/Marshaler    
    at ---Calling class---
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.marshal.Marshaler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Can you also add some exception logs?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using a dependency manager like Maven?

Comment: @GaëlJ it's true, we did it manually. Why do you ask?

Comment: I suppose using a dependency manager would avoid the trouble. Sounds the library you think is added to your project is not in reality.

Comment: Are you sure all your dependencies are using the same version? We strongly recommend using the opentelemetry-bom to keep dependencies versions in sync: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java#published-releases